# How to use i18n for attr.aria-label?

Tags: html, angular, internationalization, i18next, screen-readers

```
attr.aria-label="Manage {{useDetails?.email}}"
i18n-aria-label="User details email address manage button aria
label@@email-address-manage-button-aria-label.manage-email-address"
```

generating the `.xlf` file does not show a line for this `aria-label`

and using `i18n-attr.aria-label` the `aria-label` is no longer read by the screen reader?

what is the correct way to use i18n with the dynamic aria label that needs to use attr?

thanks!